# Link that takes current page URL and adds to it

Tags: javascript

I am creating a small multilingual (three languages) site which has a language selection dropdown. I need it so that when the user selects a new language (e.g. French), it takes the current page url and adds "-fr". For example, if the page the user is currently on is "about.html" when they select 'French' from the dropdown, it links them to "about-fr.html".

I'm guessing this is pretty straightforward if you know javascript, but I don't unfortunately, so any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Where do you stuck at? Show us the code you've tried

Comment: you should probably look at localization related code. and no, cannot answer much because, there is not enough details in your question.

Comment: Do you want the page to reload at the new location or just for the URL to change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.location.href
```

To get current window URL

then it is just string manipulation

```js
function showURL(){
  var currentURL = window.location.href;
  document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = currentURL;
}

function addFr(){
  var currentURL = window.location.href;
  document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = currentURL+"-fr";
}
```

```html
<p id="hello"><p>
<button onclick="showURL();">Get Current URL</button>

<button onclick="addFr();">URL France</button>
```

This is just a simple example you will need your custom logic based on your URLs

Comment: This won't work for the OP as your code would give about.html-fr not about-fr.html as they have requested. I know it should be a fairly simple exercise to modify your code to do this for them but they do state they don't know JS so maybe not.

Comment: @John I mentioned in example this is sample and you need to edit the string manipulation based on your urls; I am just providing what question asked not writing entire code for him

Comment: Big thanks to all who took a look at this. And of course to Shubham Srivastava for sharing an example snippet. As you can probably tell I'm new to JS as well as stack overflow. Apologies for not making myself clearer, it's a bit tricky to explain.

I just need a link that will open a different language version of the same page the user in currently on. I have an English page called about.html and I want it so when the user clicks on the link for the French version, it reads the current url (about.html) and adds "-fr" to the path so it becomes "about-fr.html" and then links to that page.

Comment: @Matt Wilde my answer was about how to get current page url if you want to redirect as well then just use window.location.href = "Your new url"; I think this is all you want; as for updating url it is just string manipulation